# Creating a datatable using makemigrations and migrate in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, admin, makemigrations

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Students(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=64),
    rollNo=models.IntegerField(),
    marks=models.IntegerField(),
    friends=models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

After applying these commands;

```
py manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
py manage.py migrate
```

the *0001_initial.py* should have hold all the features of the table. But it has only created the Id and the last column name i'm providing.

**0001_initial.py**:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.7 on 2020-01-06 08:57
```

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Students',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('friends', models.CharField(max_length=64)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

How could I store all the column names in this file so that my table will be reflected on the admin page in the browser?

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from testcase.models import Students

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    List_display=['id','name','rollNo','marks','friends']

admin.site.register(Students,StudentAdmin)
```

Comment: Remove the *trailing* commas, so the comma `,` in `models.CharField(max_length=64),` (and the following fields).

Comment: don't use `,` at the end when writing model fields

Comment: yeah, at first i thought i was creating a list. thank you for the information.